# kurento rtsp2webrtc demo keeps showing spinner instead of stream

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I'm having trouble with getting the Kurento rtsp2webrtc demo to work.
I'm talking about this application https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc

The page shows up just fine, and everything works well untill I put in the source url and try to start the stream. Upon hitting the "start" button, all I see is a spinner indicating that the stream is still being loaded. No problem, maybe I'll have to add a TURN server into the equation. But when I add the turn server in the code, the page throws an error at me:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined"

I also tried it with the version on the "release 5.1" branch instead of the master. There I do not get the aforementioned error. Instead I find the following [messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYgU4.png) in my console.

Seems alright, doesn't it? Yet still no sign of the video I want to stream through WebRTC.

I've tried it with both rtsp streams and mjpg streams, but neither of them seem to work.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I am a newbie to Kurento. I tried the code https://github.com/imonology/Kurento-H264. It worked fine for rtsp stream. Need to install kurento-media-server and then run the code.